# add same string to each line in list using python 2

Tags: python, string, list

This is my first question on stack exchange!
I have tried the answer listed here:
[Appending the same string to a list of strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050637/appending-the-same-string-to-a-list-of-strings-in-python)

edit: Turns out this is what my code really looked like:

```
working_domains = [['google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'msn.com']]
url_http = []
http = 'http://'
url_http = [http + line for line in working_domains]
print url_http
```

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' object

I'm sure i am missing something very simple here!
please help!
thanks in advance!

Comment: What you are missing, is the string markers ( `'` or `"`) when defining your list. That is where your error comes from.

Comment: Please put quotes where they belong

Comment: Please excuse me, my list actually looks like this
print working_domains
[['google.com', 'askmehow.com', 'duckduckgo.com']]
i made the list by appending the keys of a dictionary a few lines above,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you point out in your comments, `working_domains` is actually a list of lists with one element in it: `[['google.com', 'askmehow.com', 'duckduckgo.com']]`. Note the double brackets.

You can fix everything by adding this one line after your definition of `working_domains`:

```
[working_domains] = working_domains
```

This turns your list of lists of strings into a list of strings. After that, it'll look like this: `['google.com', 'askmehow.com', 'duckduckgo.com']`.

That's what you need if you want to use these other methods. You're getting your errors because the `for x in working_domains` returns the list of working domains.

---

```
working_domains = [['google.com', 'askmehow.com', 'duckduckgo.com']]
[working_domains] = working_domains
url_http = []
http = 'http://'
url_http = [http + line for line in working_domains]
print url_http
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 2 Solution:

```
working_domains = ["google.com", "yahoo.com", "msn.com"]
url_http = []
http = 'http://'
url_http = [http + line.strip() for line in working_domains]
print url_http
```

Output:

```
['http://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com', 'http://msn.com']
```

Comment: sorry, I am getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Can you post your full file? The above code is working nice and ```line``` is a variable here, not a list. May be the code is being messed up in somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `map` to achieve the desired result, although it's not that efficient and concise as a list comprehension:

```
working_domains = ["google.com", "yahoo.com", "msn.com"]
url_http = list(map(lambda original_str: "http://" + original_str, working_domains))
print(url_http)
```

**Results:** `['http://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com', 'http://msn.com']`

---

Your code was not working because you have put some extra `[]` around your list. Your first line of code should look like this instead:

```
working_domains = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'msn.com']
```