# How to concatenate a string with every element in a list of strings?

Tags: python, string, list

I want to concatenate a string with every element in a given list of strings:

```
my_variable = 'Blue'
my_list = ['House', 'Paint', 'Cloth']
```

How do I concatenate my_variable to every element in the my_list such that I have a new list

```
my_new_list = ['Blue_House', 'Blue_Paint', 'Blue_Cloth']
```

Comment: What have you tried? A simple list comprehension would do this easily.

Comment: why you tag `pandas`

Comment: Welcome to SO, this isn't a code writing service, please make an attempt and come back and ask about any problems that you cannot resolve.  Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending the same string to a list of strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050637/appending-the-same-string-to-a-list-of-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

Or use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [my_variable + '_' + e for e in my_list]
['Blue_House', 'Blue_Paint', 'Blue_Cloth']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
["_".join([my_variable, i]) for i in my_list]
# ['Blue_House', 'Blue_Paint', 'Blue_Cloth']
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list and iterate through your original list, appending the original list's entry to the new list with 'Blue_' added to the front with a simple +

```
my_variable = 'Blue'
my_list = ['House', 'Paint', 'Cloth']

new_list = []
for entry in my_list:
    new_list.append(my_variable + "_" + str(entry))

print new_list
>>>>['Blue_House', 'Blue_Paint', 'Blue_Cloth']
```

Comment: I tried but I get: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: It sounds like you're not properly iterating through your list (which contains strings) but are trying to concatenate the list itself with the string. Try running the exact code I sent, I've updated it to work with your example input.

Answer (score -1):

```
my_variable1 = 'Blue'
my_variable2 = 'Red'
my_variable3 = 'Black'
my_list = ['House', 'Paint', 'Cloth']

def mergetwo(a, b, s):
    return s.join((a,b))

def prefix(item, pre):
    return lambda sep: mergetwo(pre,item,sep)

def suffix(item, suf):
    return prefix(suf, item)

def mergewith(alist):
    return lambda position: lambda sep: lambda var: list(map(lambda item: position(item, var)(sep), alist))

def addprefix_underscore_mylist(var):
    return mergewith(my_list)(prefix)('_')(var)

def addsuffix_underscore_mylist(var):
    return mergewith(my_list)(suffix)('_')(var)

print(addprefix_underscore_mylist(my_variable1))
print(addprefix_underscore_mylist(my_variable2))
print(addprefix_underscore_mylist(my_variable3))

print(addsuffix_underscore_mylist(my_variable1))
print(addsuffix_underscore_mylist(my_variable2))
print(addsuffix_underscore_mylist(my_variable3))
```