# How to add constant string in each elements of list in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a constant value as prefix in each elements of list. I want to do something similar to  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050637/appending-the-same-string-to-a-list-of-strings-in-python) . But above answers are using for loop. I want to aviod for loops in my program.

My objective is I have to create a list it values should be `"unknown contact number 0", "unknown contact number 1","unknown contact number 2"..."unknown contact number n".` here `unknown contact number` is my prefix. I want to add this element in my list.

So far I tried this,

```
x=pd.DataFrame(index=range(val))
print ('unknown contact number '+x.index.astype(str)).values.tolist()
```

My question is Am I adding more complex to my code to avoid for loops?
or any other better approaches to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If performance is important is possible use `f-string`s, because text function in pandas are slow:

```
a = [f'unknown contact number {i}' for i in range(N)]
```

**Timings**:

```
N = 10000

In [31]: %timeit ('unknown contact number ' + pd.Series(np.arange(N)).astype(str)).tolist()
6.63 ms ± 708 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [32]: %timeit [f'unknown contact number {i}' for i in range(N)]
317 µs ± 3.61 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I understood this problem in the view of performance, for my learning can you suggest me any other better way in pandas ? +1

Comment: @MohamedThasinah - Then use `pd.Series(np.arange(N)).astype(str).radd('unknown contact number ').tolist()`, where is used function [`radd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.radd.html) - add string from right side ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using map with a lambda function if you want to avoid for loops at any cost.

```
list_ = map(lambda x : 'unknown contact number' + x, df.index.astype(str).values.tolist())
```

If you're using python 3, then map has an advantage of being lazy. Although using map with lambda function will be a bit slower than list comprehension, but if you have a custom function, you can always use it with map.