# How to do string concatenation in list with robotframework

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to do string concatenation with every listed value in robot framework

I use ride, like:

```
${list} | Create List | a | b | c |
```

I want get the new list like:

```
${list1} | a•optional | b•optional | c•optional
```

how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom keyword to achieve that you can either pass in a list object to the keyword as an argument or you can create it in python what ever suits you

ListHelper.py

```
def Catanate_Items_In_List(myList = []):
  string="•optional"
  output = ["{}{}".format(i,string) for i in myList]
  return output
```

And then In robot you can do:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  ListHelper.py


*** Test Cases ****
Catanate to Every string In a List
   ${list}  Create List  a  b  c 
   ${list1} =   Catanate Items In List   ${list}
   log  ${list1}
```

Results :

```
${list1} = ['a•optional', 'b•optional', 'c•optional']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword with a one-liner Python expression, [Appending the same string to a list of strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2050637/3820025).

```
*** Test Cases ***
Catenate
    ${list}=    Create List   a   b   c
    Log Many    @{list}
    ${new list}=    Catenate List Items    ${list}    •optional
    Log Many    @{new list}

*** Keywords ***
Catenate List Items
    [Arguments]    ${list}    ${catenate with}
    ${new list}=    Evaluate    [s + '${catenate with}' for s in ${list}]
    [return]    ${new list}
```

---

Or you can create another custom keyword that utilize Robot Framework instead of Python. For example:

1. Pass the original list and the string that should be appended to a custom keyword.
2. Make a copy.
3. Iterate through the two lists and update the values in the new one.

---

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Catenate
    ${list}=    Create List   a   b   c
    Log Many    @{list}
    ${new list}=    Catenate List Items    ${list}    •optional
    Log Many    @{new list}

*** Keywords ***
Catenate List Items
    [Arguments]    ${list}    ${catenate with}
    ${new list}=    Copy List    ${list}
    ${list length}=    Get Length    ${new list}
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${list length}
        # last parameter will be the new, catenated value
        Set List Value    ${new list}    ${i}    ${list[${i}]}${catenate with}
    END
    [return]    ${new list}
```

You can use the [Extended Variable Syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax) to access the list item value at a specific index. `${list[${i}]}` this effectively means that you get the item at position `${i}` from `${list}`. Concatenation can be done simply by passing the list item and the suffix string together, without any spaces as a new list value, `${list[${i}]}${catenate with}`. The first approach is definitely more convenient.