# (python) How do I modify a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list that looks something like this:
`days_list = ['12','554','43','2343','52']`

How do I modify it so that it looks like this: `days_list = ['days:12', 'days:554', 'days:43', 'days:2343', 'days:52']`?

Comment: days:12  value is a mix of string and int type..

Comment: It was just an example. I'll edit it.

Comment: Please show what attempts you made to resolve this. A simple google search returned the link for another stack overflow question asked over 10 years ago : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050637/appending-the-same-string-to-a-list-of-strings-in-python. Please edit your question if it's something different from that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appending the same string to a list of strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050637/appending-the-same-string-to-a-list-of-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Make a new list, based on the old, where each element is
a string with prefix "days:" and then the original value.

`days_list = ['days:{}'.format(value) for value in days_list]`

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension you can do this easily

```
result = ['days:'+item for item in days_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the code as:

```
days_list = ['days:{}'.format(value) for value in days_list]
```

or

```
days_list = [f'days:{value}' for value in days_list]
```

or

```
days_list = [f'days:{days_list[x]}' for x in range(0, len(days_list))
```