# How do you add a string to every string inside of a list?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am attempting to create a for loop to append both the contents of the first list *num* to *num2* + the word thousand.  I am looking for
`nums2 = ['one thousand', 'two thousand', 'three thousand', 'four thousand']`.  When I attempt to run this, all I am given is `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.  Any suggestions?

```
nums = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
nums2 = []

for i in nums:
     nums2.append(nums[i] + ' thousand')
```

Edit (1:13PM EST, 12/10/2020):

This question has already been asked!  My bad.
[Appending the same string to a list of strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050637/appending-the-same-string-to-a-list-of-strings-in-python)

Comment: `i` is the actual value, not the index.  No need to call `nums` again in your append statment.

Comment: `for i in nums:` could be `for i in range(len(nums)):`. Or just change `nums[i]` to `i`.

Comment: @RandomDavis it doesn't need to be an index. Just use the value.

Comment: Did you mean: `nums2 = [num + ' thousand' for num in nums]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are iterating over the `nums` list, `i` is each value in the list; on the first iteration, `i` is equal to `one`, and on the second `i` is equal to `two`.

So when you are trying to access `nums[i]` you are trying to access `nums["one"]` (on the first iteration), which obviously doesn't exist.

To solve this, you can either change the for loop to an index based one, using `range`:

```
for i in range(len(nums)):
  nums2.append(nums[i] + ' thousand')
```

Or you could just stop trying to access the list from within the loop altogether, and use the value of `i` as the prefix to append `thousand` to:

```
for i in nums:
  nums2.append(i + ' thousand')
```

Comment: Great explanation, thank you!  I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

In this case "i" is a string since strings are the elements in the list. Try just using i instead of nums[i] in the append. Example:

```
nums = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
nums2 = []

for i in nums:
     nums2.append(i + ' thousand')
```

Answer (score 0):

the variable i in your for loop refer to the individual elements of the nums list, which in this case are strings. You need integers as indexes so in your case, the for loop can be modified as:

```
for i,k in enumerate(nums):
 nums2.append(nums[i] + ' thousand')
```

You can check if you got it right by printing nums2:

```
print(nums2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
nums = ["Ford", "Volvo", "BMW"]
nums2 = []

for i in nums:
  nums2.append(i + ' thousand')
```