# Append different strings to a list of strings depending on its position in the list

Tags: python, string, list, loops, append

Given the following list of configurations

```
['configuration1A', 'configuration1B', 'configuration1C', 'configuration2A', 'configuration2B', 'configuration2C', 'configuration3A', 'configuration3B', 'configuration3C', 'configuration4A', 'configuration4B', 'configuration4C', 'configuration5A', 'configuration5B', 'configuration5C', 'configuration6A', 'configuration6B', 'configuration6C', 'configuration7A', 'configuration7B', 'configuration7C', 'configuration8A', 'configuration8B', 'configuration8C', 'configuration9A', 'configuration9B', 'configuration9C', 'configuration10A', 'configuration10B', 'configuration10C', 'configuration11A', 'configuration11B', 'configuration11C', 'configuration12A', 'configuration12B', 'configuration12C', 'configuration13A', 'configuration13B', 'configuration13C', 'configuration14A', 'configuration14B', 'configuration14C', 'configuration15A', 'configuration15B', 'configuration15C', 'configuration16A', 'configuration16B', 'configuration16C', 'configuration17A', 'configuration17B', 'configuration17C', 'configuration18A', 'configuration18B', 'configuration18C', 'configuration19A', 'configuration19B', 'configuration19C', 'configuration20A', 'configuration20B', 'configuration20C', 'configuration21A', 'configuration21B', 'configuration21C', 'configuration22A', 'configuration22B', 'configuration22C', 'configuration23A', 'configuration23B', 'configuration23C', 'configuration24A', 'configuration24B', 'configuration24C', 'configuration25A', 'configuration25B', 'configuration25C', 'configuration1A', 'configuration1B', 'configuration1C', 'configuration2A', 'configuration2B', 'configuration2C', 'configuration3A', 'configuration3B', 'configuration3C', 'configuration4A', 'configuration4B', 'configuration4C', 'configuration5A', 'configuration5B', 'configuration5C', 'configuration6A', 'configuration6B', 'configuration6C', 'configuration7A', 'configuration7B', 'configuration7C', 'configuration8A', 'configuration8B', 'configuration8C', 'configuration9A', 'configuration9B', 'configuration9C', 'configuration10A', 'configuration10B', 'configuration10C', 'configuration11A', 'configuration11B', 'configuration11C', 'configuration12A', 'configuration12B', 'configuration12C', 'configuration13A', 'configuration13B', 'configuration13C', 'configuration14A', 'configuration14B', 'configuration14C', 'configuration15A', 'configuration15B', 'configuration15C', 'configuration16A', 'configuration16B', 'configuration16C', 'configuration17A', 'configuration17B', 'configuration17C', 'configuration18A', 'configuration18B', 'configuration18C', 'configuration19A', 'configuration19B', 'configuration19C', 'configuration20A', 'configuration20B', 'configuration20C', 'configuration21A', 'configuration21B', 'configuration21C', 'configuration22A', 'configuration22B', 'configuration22C', 'configuration23A', 'configuration23B', 'configuration23C', 'configuration24A', 'configuration24B', 'configuration24C', 'configuration25A', 'configuration25B', 'configuration25C', 'configuration1A', 'configuration1B', 'configuration1C', 'configuration2A', 'configuration2B', 'configuration2C', 'configuration3A', 'configuration3B', 'configuration3C', 'configuration4A', 'configuration4B', 'configuration4C', 'configuration5A', 'configuration5B', 'configuration5C', 'configuration6A', 'configuration6B', 'configuration6C', 'configuration7A', 'configuration7B', 'configuration7C', 'configuration8A', 'configuration8B', 'configuration8C', 'configuration9A', 'configuration9B', 'configuration9C', 'configuration10A', 'configuration10B', 'configuration10C', 'configuration11A', 'configuration11B', 'configuration11C', 'configuration12A', 'configuration12B', 'configuration12C', 'configuration13A', 'configuration13B', 'configuration13C', 'configuration14A', 'configuration14B', 'configuration14C', 'configuration15A', 'configuration15B', 'configuration15C', 'configuration16A', 'configuration16B', 'configuration16C', 'configuration17A', 'configuration17B', 'configuration17C', 'configuration18A', 'configuration18B', 'configuration18C', 'configuration19A', 'configuration19B', 'configuration19C', 'configuration20A', 'configuration20B', 'configuration20C', 'configuration21A', 'configuration21B', 'configuration21C', 'configuration22A', 'configuration22B', 'configuration22C', 'configuration23A', 'configuration23B', 'configuration23C', 'configuration24A', 'configuration24B', 'configuration24C', 'configuration25A', 'configuration25B', 'configuration25C']
```

How does one append a string at the end of each element (string) with specific constraints:

• Add string="1" to the first 75 elements (`configuration1A1`, and so on)

• Add string="2" to the next 75 elements (`configuration1A2`, and so on)

• Add string="3" to the last 75 elements (`configuration1A3`, and so on)

In order to add the string at the end of a string, one can do the following

```
config_numb="1"
configurations_new = [x + config_numb for i in configurations_v1]
```

So far, I have the following

```
count = 0

for x in configurations_v1:
    
    if count < 75:
        #print(x)
        config_numb="1"
        configurations_new = [x + config_numb for i in configurations_v1]
        
        pass
    elif count >= 75 and count < 150:
        #print(x)
        config_numb="2"
        configurations_new = [x + config_numb for i in configurations_v1]
        pass
    
    elif count >= 150:
        #print(x)
        config_numb="3"
        configurations_new = [x + config_numb for i in configurations_v1]
        pass
    
    count += 1
```

But this is creating a list with the len() required, however, instead of having all the elements in the configuration list with their respective `config_numb` at the end, every element is `configuration25C3`.

```
['configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3', 'configuration25C3']
```

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2050637/7109869), but that one only considers the appending of the same string, which is not the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is list comprehension iterates over an entire iterable and creates a new list, you can add conditions to the value but just iterating might in fact be easier to understand for people, also one more thing to note is strings are **immutable** i.e. when you are saying modify you are in fact creating a new string. Try this:

```
configurations_new = configurations_v1.copy()
for index, value in enumerate(configurations_v1):
    if index < 75:
        configurations_new[index] = configurations_new[index] + '1'
    elif index < 150:
        configurations_new[index] = configurations_new[index] + '2'
    else:
        configurations_new[index] = configurations_new[index] + '3'
```

Which when written using list comprehension is:

```
configurations_new = [i + '1' if index < 75 else i + '2' if index < 150 else i + '3' for index, i in enumerate(configurations_v1)]
```