# Add extension to the file names in a list (Python)

Tags: python

I got an output list in python as shown below. It there any possible way to add ".txt" behind each items in the list?

```
['img20210216-160215-80_RASM_RO_3227_88', 'img20210216-160215-35_RASM_LI_226_62', 'img20210216-160213-61_FKTH_LIT_231_97', 'img20210216-160218-22_FKTH_RIT_1235_78', 'img20210216-160217-47_FKTH_LIB_239_75', 'img20201017-105223-50']
```

Comment: `[f'{i}.txt' for i in input_list]` Py 3.6+

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appending the same string to a list of strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050637/appending-the-same-string-to-a-list-of-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

```py
lst = ['img20210216-160215-80_RASM_RO_3227_88', 'img20210216-160215-35_RASM_LI_226_62',
       'img20210216-160213-61_FKTH_LIT_231_97', 'img20210216-160218-22_FKTH_RIT_1235_78',
       'img20210216-160217-47_FKTH_LIB_239_75', 'img20201017-105223-50']

new_list = tuple(f"{i}.txt" for i in lst)
print(new_list)
# ('img20210216-160215-80_RASM_RO_3227_88.txt', 'img20210216-160215-35_RASM_LI_226_62.txt',
#  'img20210216-160213-61_FKTH_LIT_231_97.txt', 'img20210216-160218-22_FKTH_RIT_1235_78.txt',
#  'img20210216-160217-47_FKTH_LIB_239_75.txt', 'img20201017-105223-50.txt')
```

Use a **tuple** so that you don't get any error while you do file operation with the list of names.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = ['img20210216-160215-80_RASM_RO_3227_88', 'img20210216-160215-35_RASM_LI_226_62', 'img20210216-160213-61_FKTH_LIT_231_97', 'img20210216-160218-22_FKTH_RIT_1235_78', 'img20210216-160217-47_FKTH_LIB_239_75', 'img20201017-105223-50']

new_list = [i + '.txt' for i in my_list]
```

will add '.txt' to the end of each item in `my_list`.